# Cannot position display:table with position:absolute

Tags: html, css

I am using this css to center (headct) in vertical and horizontal. I have to add display:table because I want center elements inside it with display:table-cell;

```
.headct {
    height: 283px;
    background: url(../images/icon/bg1.png);
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: 120px;
}
.head-inner {
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

HTML like this:

```
<div class="headct">
   <div class="head-inner">
        The content
   </div>
</div>
```

It only works on Chrome but it does not work on firefox or others. Please help me to correct it. Thank so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you really want to display tabular data, excel style, in your page, I would vote against table layout. I would look at a flex layout which is fairly simple to use to center/align/justify components vertically or horizontally. For example in your case,

Something like this:

```
.headct {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; <-- you can use whatever values but you have to specify a size
}
.head-inner {
 <-- nothing special to put here
}
```

But if you want to stick with table layout, adding a width to your element that has display table solves the problem. For example:

```
.headct {
    height: 100%;
    width: 800px;
    background: url(../images/icon/bg1.png);
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.head-inner {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

`vertical-align: middle` centers the component relatively to the size of it's parent, so if you want to center it vertically you can add a height of 100%. Also, as far as I'm aware, the margin: 0 auto trick only works for horizontal alignment, so if you want margins on top/bottom you have to give them sizes by yourself. Another argument in favor of flex layout imo.

**Oh, and it might be a typo but you were missing the '.' for your head-inner class.**

Comment: Great solution. I just updated and it working well. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo (`headct` lacks of `.`):

```css
.headct {
    height: 283px;
    background: url(../images/icon/bg1.png);
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: 120px;
}
.head-inner {
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="headct">
   <div class="head-inner">
        The content
   </div>
</div>
```